# reverse for loop for array countdown

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, reverse

I get the error..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Reverse.main(Reverse.java:20).
```

There is not wrong in the syntax so im not sure why when it compiles it gets an error?

```
public class Reverse {

public static void main(String [] args){
    int i, j;


    System.out.print("Countdown\n");

    int[] numIndex = new int[10]; // array with 10 elements.

    for (i = 0; i<11 ; i++) {
        numIndex[i] = i;// element i = number of iterations (index 0=0, 1=1, ect.)
    }

    for (j=10; j>=0; j--){ // could have used i, doesn't matter.
        System.out.println(numIndex[j]);//indexes should print in reverse order from here but it throws an exception?
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the array is 10 elements long.  you iterate from 0 to 10, that is 11! that causes the index out of bounds error.  You should really use numIndex.length in the future to prevent these sort of arbitrary numbers

Comment: ah right again sir haha. Thank you @greedybuddah - new guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java uses 0-based array indexes. When you create an Array of size 10 `new int[10]` it creates 10 integer 'cells' in the array. The indexes are: 0, 1, 2, ...., 8, 9.

Your loop counts to the index which is 1 less than 11, or 10, and that index does not exist.

Answer (score 23):

You declared array on integers of `10 elements`. And you are iterating from `i=0 to i=10` and `i=10 to i=0` that's `11 elements`. Obviously it's an `index out of bounds error`.

Change your code to this

```
public class Reverse {

  public static void main(String [] args){
    int i, j;

    System.out.print("Countdown\n");

    int[] numIndex = new int[10]; // array with 10 elements.

    for (i = 0; i<10 ; i++) {  // from 0 to 9
      numIndex[i] = i;// element i = number of iterations (index 0=0, 1=1, ect.)
    }

    for (j=9; j>=0; j--){ // from 9 to 0
      System.out.println(numIndex[j]);//indexes should print in reverse order from here but it throws an exception?   
    } 

  }
}
```

> Remember indices starts from 0.

.

Answer (score 1):

The array is of size 10, which means it is indexable from 0 to 9. `numIndex[10]` is indeed out of bounds. This is a basic off-by-one error.

Answer (score 1):

An `Array` in java that has `10` elements goes from `0` to `9`. So your loops need to cover this range. Currently you are going from `0` to `10`, and `10` to `0`.